# qgraph in R shortens node labels

Tags: r, plot, graph, igraph, r-qgraph

I am using qgraph in R. It automatically shortens node labels, which can be very useful. But how do I ask it to use full labels?

Here is an example.

```
require(qgraph)
m <- matrix(1,3,3)
colnames(m) <- c("AAAAAAAA", "BBBBBBBB", "CCCCCCCC")
qgraph(m)
```

[image: shortened node labels example]

Comment: If you set them in the labels argument they won't abbreviate: `qgraph(m, labels = colnames(m))`

Answer (score 1):

As Jac said in the comments, you need to manually overwrite the labels with `qgraph(m, labels = colnames(m))`.